# PhantomJS/CasperJS client side usage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there any possibility or solution to run casperJS and post form data client side? I need to post user data to an external website form but it needs to be done through the ip address of the user.

Thank you!

Comment: It this for testing or is this on an actual website? Because I'm not sure why you'd need the latter case - you could just use normal JS to post any form.

Comment: Actual web app, just edited my question. I need to post to an external website form